# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, openlayers-3

url automatic convert http to https. map and geoserver layer is nos visble.

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
 url: 'http://117.252.14.233:8080/geoserver/Watersheds/wms',
 params: { 'LAYERS': 'Watersheds:as_riv_15s', 'TILED': true },
 serverType: 'geoserver',
 //crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
 transition: 0,
});

var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
source: wmsSource
```

});

```
var view = new ol.View({
center: [0, 0],
zoom: 1
});

var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [wmsLayer],
target: 'map',
view: view
});

map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
    { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html' });
if (url) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
        '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
   }
 });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9H8U.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs on https but you do not control the wms server you will be restricted to old browsers which do not force https such as Internet Explorer, or you must use a proxy on your own server.  A typical example is the BGS Geology service described here https://www.bgs.ac.uk/technologies/web-map-services-wms/web-map-services-geology-625k/

For that you would need a simple proxy such as

```
<?php 
 $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
 if($method == "GET"){
   $url = 'http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
   if ($httpCode == 200) {
     echo $result;
   }
 }
?>
```

When the proxy script is named bgs625.php the normal wms url in the OpenLayers code can be replaced with `url: 'bgs625.php',`